# xsl:for-each-group the output of "fn:unparsed-text-lines()" (using the "group-starting-with" attribute)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a text file containing lines like this:

```
ABC
DEF
 GHI
JKL
 MNO
 PQR
 STU
VWX
YZA
```

So I read the lines of this file with XSLT-3.0's `fn:unparsed-text-lines('fileName','UTF-8')` and I want to group/merge the lines with the following lines that start with a space and wrap them in elements. For example, using `xsl:for-each-group`:

```
<line>ABC</line>
<line>DEF GHI</line>
<line>JKL MNO PQR STU</line>
<line>VWX</line>
<line>YZA</line>
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use `xsl:for-each-group` with a sequence of `xs:strings` with XSLT-3.0. Do I have to convert the strings to nodes first? Or is there a better way?

Here is the dysfunctional XSLT attempt (the predicate is merely a hint and does not work):

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="unparsed-text-lines('filename.txt','utf-8')" group-starting-with="text()[not(starts-with(.,' '))]">
  <line><xsl:value-of select="string-join(current-group(),'DELIMITER')"/></line>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are not text nodes. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$lines" group-starting-with=".[not(starts-with(.,' '))]">
    <line>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=""/>
    </line>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: So close :-/ Thank you.